# UIImageView from URL rotation causes image to appear zoomed out? (Swift 5, Xcode 11)

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uiimageview, uiimage

Hello Im using UIImageView to display an Image from URL.

When downloaded and displayed the image is shown in full screen from left to right, but after rotating looks like its zoomed out, how can I fill it to full screen following rotation?

Download Image Controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Image1: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var Image2: UILabel!

var ImageStore: UIImage!

let imageUrl = URL(string: "https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/landscape_6.png")!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any)
{
    downloadImage(with: imageUrl)
}

func downloadImage(with url: URL)
{
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.Image2.text = "Download Complete"
            self.ImageStore = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }.resume()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! ChartAController

    destinationViewController.TransferImage = ImageStore
}
```

Show Image and Rotate Controller:

```
    Chart1.image = TransferImage
    Chart1.transform = Chart1.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
```

Result:

Image Without Rotating stretched to edges:
[image]

Image with rotations:
[image]

Comment: What is your imageview contentMode?

Comment: I have set it now to Chart1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill. It works by zooming in, but now it zoomed in slightly too much and edges are cropped